# How to convert Set containing values into string

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, set, hashset

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "abcdaa";
        dups(str);
    }
    public static void dups(String str){
        HashSet hs = new HashSet();
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i < ch.length;i++){
            hs.add(ch[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(hs);
    }
```

The above code return Output: **[a,b,c,d]**

But I want to print the Set values into a string so I can return a string value return value looks like this:Expected Output: **abcd**

Comment: Take a look at `java.util.StringJoiner`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "abcdaa";
        dups(str);
    }

    public static void dups(String str) {
        HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            if(hs.add(ch[i])){
                sb.append(ch[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
public static void dups(String str) {
            HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Character character : str.toCharArray()) {
                if(hs.add(character)){
                    sb.append(character);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
```

I can't think a better way to do this...
It's better use StringBuilder instead of String, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532483/6949032

Comment: Why not use modern language features?
`System.out.println(hs.stream().collect(Collectors.joining()));`

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Java 8 stream =S

Comment: thanks @ErickMaia.. it was working.. But I am looking to optimize that instead of using StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why no one had mentioned this yet, but it's pretty simple in Java 8:

```
System.out.println(String.join("", hs));
```

Note that if you want to preserve the original order, you'll need to use `LinkedHashSet` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = "abcdaa";
    String result = dups(str);
    System.out.println(result);
}
public static String dups(String str){
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    String strss = "";
    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i < ch.length;i++){
        if(hs.add(ch[i])){
            strss +=ch[i];
        }
    }
    return strss;
}
```

Comment: the return is not `abcd`=(

Comment: Yes .. Return is not abcd

Comment: I have checked, it returns "abcd"

Comment: `strss +=` is a bad idea as a new String is allocated every time. This is exactly what StringBuilder is for

Comment: a new String, I think, it's a good idea, because you will have always new instance, sometimes it can untie misunderstanding

Comment: Strings are immutable so there's no value in a new instance

Comment: Yes, you're right, in this example, "strss" will have no value. I was considering the case where we have a new instance

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a third-party library, the `CharAdapter` class in [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) can solve the problem.

```
String str = "abcdaa";
CharAdapter distinct = CharAdapter.adapt(str).distinct();
System.out.println(distinct);
```

You can see what the code does [here](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/impl/string/immutable/CharAdapter.java#L140).  Using a `java.util.HashSet` will box the char values as `Character` objects.  The distinct method in `CharAdapter` uses a `CharHashSet` which does not need to box the `char` values.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.